# rails return tuples with common attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display all the movies by selected director.  Routes and controller work fine. However, the filtered movies shown in view are all the same. For example, I have four movies of which two have the same director. What I want is to show these two different tuples in view page, but the shown two tuples are the same. This is the controller code:

```
def find_movies_by_same_director
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @director = @movie.director
  if (not @director.nil?) and (not @director.empty?)
    #@movies = Movie.find_all_by_director(@director) if (not @director.nil?) and (not @director.empty?);
    @movies = Movie.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM movies i WHERE i.director == '#{@director}'")
    render :director 
  else
    flash[:notice] = "'#{@movie.title}' has no director information"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I try both ways, find_by_sql and find_by_all,  to find the tuples, but they both get the same results.
This is the view code:

```
%tbody
- @movies.each do |movie|
  %tr 
    %th= @movie.title
    %th= @movie.rating
    %th= @movie.release_date
```

I'm new to rails, so any comments or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question, but a more standard Rails way of performing the search in line 6 would be `@movies = Movie.where(director: @director)`. Better yet, since you don't need to use `@director` in your view, do `director = @movie.director` and then `@movies = Movie.where(director: director)`.

Comment: It works! thank you so much for your detailed reply.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer when you have a moment.

Comment: I have accepted it! I just know this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view code, you are using the instance variable `@movie`, which returns the result of your original search from line 2 of your controller code. To see each movie as you iterate through @movies, you need to use the local variable that you are declaring in the block.

```
%tbody
- @movies.each do |movie|
  %tr 
    %th= movie.title
    %th= movie.rating
    %th= movie.release_date
```

If that's confusing, you might change the name of the block variable entirely. This doesn't change the result but might be more readable.

```
%tbody
- @movies.each do |matched_movie|
  %tr 
    %th= matched_movie.title
    %th= matched_movie.rating
    %th= matched_movie.release_date
```

EDIT: (It was suggested that I add my comment to this answer.)

This is unrelated to your question, but a more standard Rails way of performing the search in line 6 would be `@movies = Movie.where(director: @director)`. Better yet, since you don't need to use @director in your view, you could do:

```
director = @movie.director
@movies = Movie.where(director: director)
```

Comment: I think you should include your comment in the answer too, the comment has good advice.